# How to define an audience with event count>0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

Hi everyone I am trying to configure Firebase for android and iOS platform and I am having some issues creating audience using event count and parameter. For ex, I'am trying to create an audience with the event "ecommerce_purchase", with this configuration:
[audience_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgDn6.jpg)

But almost one week later I still can't see any users in this audience, knowing that everyday there are users making purchases and Firebase can also identify them in the "event" tab, with more than 1000 users in the same period. Tried to create audience with other default events too (add_to_cart, begin_checkout etc.), and a couple of custom event with similar configuration and none is working, what are we missing?

Comment: Can you please turn on debug mode and provide some device logs after logging those events and running the app for about a minute? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexD hi Alex thanks for your comment, it seems to start working now, didn't figure out why it took so long to appear users in the audiences but it's populating now

Comment: There is a threshold for audience results to appear on the site (> 10 users). Even you have 1000 users but less than 10 users that are qualified, you may not see it. There might be some factors that I don't know on top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

**If your goal is for Notifications**

Think opposite, create the audience with the =1 OR >1 and select the "Does not include all of". Please check the attached screenshot for better understanding.

[Reference from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437923/firebase-audience-targeting-on-count-operators/47438599#47438599)

**Create Audience**: 
[image]

**Condition in Notification** 
[image]